# Problem integrating OCL types in Xtext grammar

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, osgi, xtext

I'm working on a grammar (Xtext project) where I want to reuse OCL types. Usually you refer in Xtext to existing types with an import statement, e.g.

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
```

There is already an example Xtext project (CompleteOCL) which integrates OCL types in a grammar. Unfortunately the project refers in its import statements to local plugins, e.g.

```
import "platform:/resource/org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.base/model/BaseCST.ecore" as base
```

So there are no dependencies defined in the Manifest.MF file. If I want to reuse OCL types in my grammar I have to write for example

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/ocl/3.0.0/BaseCST" as base
```

I've added the  org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.base dependency and can write rules in my grammar which refer to (OCL) BaseCST types. If I try to generate the Xtext artifcats I get the following error:

```
     ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.SettingProviderImpl$1$1.setValue(SettingProviderImpl.java:54)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Problem parsing 'classpath:/org/xtext/example/mydsl/MyDsl.xtext':[XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:5 Couldn't resolve reference to EPackage 'http://www.eclipse.org/ocl/3.0.0/BaseCST'.]
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.LanguageConfig.setUri(LanguageConfig.java:112)
    ... 41 more
```

So probably I'missing something? The problem is quite easy to reproduce. Create a new Xtext project, add the dependency, edit the grammar and add the last import statement ("import "http://...") and try to generate the Xtext artifacts. Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks in advance!
  Michael

EDIT: In order to use a grammar you have to refer in your MWE2 workflow (see section 3.2.2.2 of the the Xtext documentation (version 1.0.1)) to the corresponding genmodel file of the ecore model, for example

```
fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.ecore.EcoreGeneratorFragement {
  referencedGenModels = "platform:/plugins/org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.base/model/BaseCST.genmodel
}
```

Nevertheless it's still not working for me.

Comment: Depending on what you need, maybe the Check language might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CompleteOCL project part of the Eclipse workspace that contains your Xtext project? If so you could try to reference the Ecore file using the platform URI you mentioned:

```
import "platform:/resource/org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.base/model/BaseCST.ecore" as base
```

instead of

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/ocl/3.0.0/BaseCST" as base
```

If the CompleteOCL project's bundles are part of your Eclipse target platform (e.g., part of your Eclipse installation), then the

```
Couldn't resolve reference to EPackage 'http://www.eclipse.org/ocl/3.0.0/BaseCST'
```

error imho indicates that the bundle providing this EPackage is not activated.

Comment: Hi Frank, the project is not part of my eclipse project space. I've took the source jars of the corresponding packages and tried to add them manually to my workspace (import projects, etc.) but this hasn't change anything at all. How do I check if a bundle is activated or not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To check if a bundle is activated go to menu Help > About Eclipse > Installation details > Plug-ins tab and check if the plug-in/bundle containing the Ecore model file is listed.

Comment: Here's anther way to check whether a bundle is activated or not: You could also start Eclipse with the OSGi console enabled (by appending '-console' to your eclipse start command) and then use the 'ss' OSGi console command to get a list (and activation state) of the available bundles. Using the console you could also force a bundle to be activated (using the 'start' command).

Comment: Okay, the package which contains the ecore file is listed in the plugin tabs :-(

Comment: You might try to check whether the EPackage is actually registered in the global EPackage registry. Try something like

org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage("http://www.eclipse.org/ocl/3.0.0/BaseCST")

in a small plug-in project and check whether it returns an EPackage. Make sure that the bundle which contains the ecore file is part of your launch configuration that executes the plug-in project above.

Comment: Hi, I've created a plugin project and tried to get a epackage instance and it's working.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm running out of ideas. You should probably post to the Xtext news group. I guess they should know whats going on...

Comment: You are quite welcome! BTW: In case you do post to the Xtext news group, it might be beneficial for others having similar problems when you could provide a link to your post here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot should be to install that grammar within your eclipse.
Import your CompleteOCL project. Then right click on it>export>deployable plug-ins and fragments>check CompleteOCL project>and click the radio button install into host>Click finish and restart Eclipse.

Now your should be able to make your import as `import "http://www.eclipse.org/ocl/3.0.0/BaseCST" as base`

Regards,

Xavier